# how to set the Theano flag warn.sum_div_dimshuffle_bug to False

Tags: python, warnings, theano

I am using the theano package to find the derivative of a sigmoid function, using the cross entropy as the cost. This is my code:

```
 variable = tensor.dmatrix('variable')
 y= tensor.nnet.softmax(tensor.dot(z,variable))
 cost =tensor.sum( tensor.nnet.binary_crossentropy(y,y))
 gp = tensor.grad(cost,variable)
 dlogistic = function([variable],gp)
```

when I run my code, I get the following error:

```
 WARNING (theano.tensor.opt): WARNING: Your current code is fine,
 but Theano versions between rev. 3bd9b789f5e8 (2010-06-16) and 
 cfc6322e5ad4 (2010-08-03) would have given an incorrect result. 
 To disable this warning, set the Theano flag warn.sum_div_dimshuffle_bug
 to False.
```

But I dont know how to do that. I tried this:

```
 warn.sum_div_dimshuffle_bug= false
```

but it is giving me an error on warn, saying it is not recognized as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from theano import config
config.warn.sum_div_dimshuffle_bug = False
```

This worked for me

Comment: There is other way to change Theano flags explained here: http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html. For example, use the environment variable THEANO_FLAGS=warn.sum_div_dimshuffle_bug=False.